# Codeigniter email class, unexpected if

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

I am trying to send email use codeigniter email class via passing data into the following parenthese .

```
 $this->email->message('Whatever message you want to email')
```

The following works

```
$this->email->message('Your name is '.$data->name.'');
```

but the following will give the error. "unexpected if"

```
$this->email->message('You have ordered:'.
                       if(isset($result->order)){
                            //show order detail
                        }else{
                            "nothing"
                       }.'');
```

What is the correct way to achieve this.

and also if I want to include a foreach loop after the `if(isset` how would that work.

Comment: That is not a valid location for an `if(){}` block. You can look into [ternary operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) is you would like.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is **NOT** a function. It cannot be used as a "data source" for variable assignments.

```
$foo = if(...) { ... } // illegal syntax.
```

should be written as

```
if (...) {
   $foo = true result
else {
   $foo = false result
}

$this->email->message('You have ordered:'. $foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "ternary operator":

```
<?php
$this->email->message('You have ordered: ' . isset($result->order) ? '...' : 'nothing');
```

Here the `'...'` obviously is only a placeholder for whatever "details" you want to show. This certainly can be a previously prepared string variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I think this might be it. I havent tried it yet, but what does the ? mark do

Comment: Well, take a look at the documentation I referenced: it evaluates the operand to the left, decides if it is true or not. Depending on that it chooses the first (true) or second(false) alternative on the right.

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this:

```
$temp = isset($result->order) ? "" : "nothing";

$this->email->message('You have ordered:'.$temp.'');
```